# Do sinch servers do anything to detect and block spamming?

Tags: android, sinch

I would like to use sinch, but I am concerned about trolls decompiling my app's apk and having a field day spamming sinch instant messages to other users.

Do sinch servers do anything at the moment to detect users sending abnormal amounts of messages per second?

In addition to that, is there any detection around multiple connections to sinch servers under many different user id but from one ip adress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should authenticate using a service side ticket https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android#applicationauthentication to avoid someone from obtaining your secret. 
There is no velocity checks on our side, we have many different use cases for the messages so we don't throttle at all.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks!